# Passing parameters via onclick to HandlebarsJS partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have a few `<div>` tags that trigger a modal. The modal is a partial included on the page. I want to change the text inside the modal depending on the `<div>` that was clicked. I can't figure out how to pass a variable to the partial when the `<div>` is clicked. Any ideas?

```
<div data-open="config">
    <a href="">link 1</a>
</div>
<div data-open="config">
    <a href="">link 2</a>
</div>
{{> My_modal}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) of the `open` event handler.

You could place here a function that do all the job you need when the dialog is open.

But you have to find a way to get your clicked element, as the provided event is just something from jquery dialog.

You could do by set some css class on selected element on click handler.

And then you get it in other functions when you need.

But you can do the job in the place where you open the dialog.

In this function you have access to the clicked element and could get the text easy.

And then just compile your handlebars template with your infos.

Have a look at this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/alexmario/f0fxvqrj/20/).

Just close the dialog and then click on one of the links, you see the text inside the dialog change based on link selected.

Comment: _And then just compile your handlebars template with your infos._  How do I do this part?

Comment: Yes, but you have to get the `message` from your div element, let me set a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: Are you saying to put the compile code inside the open() function?

Comment: Is this possible to do using precompiled templates?

Comment: Do you mean to compile the template just one and then use it in the handler function where you open the dialog? Of course. You just need to have access to the precompiled template.

Comment: "Handlebars.compile is not a function" because i'm using the runtime version of handlebars for compilation.

Comment: You have `Handlebars.templates` ?

Comment: I have some templates, yes.

Comment: So just use `Handlebars.templates.myprecompiled(context, options)` as is shown [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html)

Comment: I guess I don't know what I need to be replacing?

Comment: Could you fork the jsfidde of my answer and change it as you need. Then you can came back with the issue and a full code example.

Comment: The only thing that needs to change is putting the modal in a partial. That partial is precompiled so I need to be able to pass data to it based on the clicked div

Comment: I have improoved my [exampe](https://jsfiddle.net/alexmario/f0fxvqrj/28/) please have a look if this is near what you asked.